# Why does the page scroll up when clicking on gallery thumbnail?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I have a photo gallery that's doing some strange behavior I'm unable to figure out. When clicking on the thumbnail which is supposed to show me the image, it not only does that, but it also scrolls up the page. If the gallery shows up a little beneath the top of the screen, it will make it scroll up, and if it's passing the top of the screen it will make it scroll down until the top of the Gallery section is aligned with the top of the screen.

I tried to replicate what I did on codepen: https://codepen.io/dmontesi/pen/VJZeVq. I'm only using SCSS/HTML.

```
<!-- Gallery -->
<section class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__gall">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/11/49/architecture-1477103_960_720.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/11/48/architecture-1477101_960_720.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li id="slide3"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/11/46/architecture-1477099_960_720.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li>
                <a href="#slide1"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/11/49/architecture-1477103_960_720.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/11/48/architecture-1477101_960_720.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#slide3"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/24/11/46/architecture-1477099_960_720.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I only want it to show the next slide and don't move the user's position on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

( You can see the full code here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/KjKwJz) )

**Question:**

Why when you click a navigation link, it will scroll to top of image? and how to prevent it?

**Answer:**

Well, That's the natural behavior of link. that's called anchor link.

if you use `<a href="#slide1">` , when user clicks on it, page will scroll to an element with `id = slide1`.

you can prevent that (by adding `onclick="event.preventDefault()"`), but it means you can't use css `:target` rule anymore. it means target image will not be shown anymore on top of other images.

Instead, you can use javascript, to control full behavior.

1. Add a onclick handler to your navigation links:

```
<a href="#slide1"  onclick='navigate(event)'>
```

2. you should write a javascript navigate function. this function should give class `active` from current `active` element, and give it to clicked one. like this:

```
function navigate(event){
  //get active element
  var active = event.target.closest(".wrapper").getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
  //remove class "active" from active element
  if(active)active.classList.remove("active");
  //get target element from link
  var target = document.getElementById(event.target.closest("a").getAttribute("href").replace("#",""));
  //add class "active" to the target
  target.classList.add("active");
  //prevent default link behaviour
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

3. then we should write a css rule for active image (it's replaced the `li:target` selector.):

```
.slides li.active {
  z-index: 3;
}
.slides li:not(.active) {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

( You can see the full code here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/KjKwJz) )

Comment: @DanMontesinos updated the answer so you can see how to link to images.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for posting the pen. I see it's still making the page scroll up and down to the anchor link, but your suggestion makes a lot of sense, if instead of pointing to the anchor links, I change it to point directly to an image. I'll play with it and keep you posted.

Comment: @DanMontesinos oops, you want the slider to slide to that image, not direct linking to image, right? will update the answer in minutes.

Comment: @DanMontesinos is it ok to use javascript?

Comment: sure, that would also work. All I'm trying to do is for it to slide, but not to move up or down depending on where you are on the page.

Comment: @DanMontesinos sorry for wrong timing. i can't manage my time most of the times. updated the answer , and its now working as you described.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was driving back from work. That's awesome! It's exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks so much for all the help!